# Can't setup spark application with spark-atlas-connector

Tags: apache-spark, apache-atlas

Can't setup my spark application with apache atlas via spark-atlas-connector .

I had clone https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/spark-atlas-connector project and executed **mvn package**. Then I put all jars in my project and setup config like this:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("atlas-test")
      .setMaster("local[2]")
      .set("spark.extraListeners", "com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.SparkAtlasEventTracker")
      .set("spark.sql.queryExecutionListeners", "com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.SparkAtlasEventTracker")
      .set("spark.sql.streaming.streamingQueryListeners", "com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.SparkAtlasStreamingQueryEventTracker")

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .config(sparkConf)
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._


    val df = spark.read.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", BROKER_SERVERS)
      .option("subscribe", "foobar")
      .option("startingOffset", "earliest")
      .load()

    df.show()

    df.write
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", BROKER_SERVERS)
      .option("topic", "foobar-out")
      .save()

  }
```

**Atlas** is started via docker container which I pulled.
**Kafka with Zookeper** are stared via docker container which I pulled too.

The job works without spark-atlas-connector but when I want to add a connector it throws exceptions.

```
19/08/09 16:40:16 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception when registering SparkListener
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.setupAndStartListenerBus(SparkContext.scala:2398)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:555)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
    at Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.atlas.AtlasException: Failed to load application properties
    at org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties.get(ApplicationProperties.java:134)
    at org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties.get(ApplicationProperties.java:86)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.AtlasClientConf.configuration$lzycompute(AtlasClientConf.scala:25)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.AtlasClientConf.configuration(AtlasClientConf.scala:25)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.AtlasClientConf.get(AtlasClientConf.scala:50)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.AtlasClient$.atlasClient(AtlasClient.scala:120)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.SparkAtlasEventTracker.<init>(SparkAtlasEventTracker.scala:33)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.SparkAtlasEventTracker.<init>(SparkAtlasEventTracker.scala:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$loadExtensions$1.apply(Utils.scala:2691)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$loadExtensions$1.apply(Utils.scala:2680)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.loadExtensions(Utils.scala:2680)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$setupAndStartListenerBus$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:2387)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$setupAndStartListenerBus$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:2386)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.setupAndStartListenerBus(SparkContext.scala:2386)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.shade.org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: Cannot locate configuration source null
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.shade.org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:259)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.shade.org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:238)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.shade.org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:197)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.shade.org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration.<init>(PropertiesConfiguration.java:284)
    at org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties.<init>(ApplicationProperties.java:69)
    at org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties.get(ApplicationProperties.java:125)
    ... 32 more
19/08/09 16:40:16 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext already stopped.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception when registering SparkListener
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.setupAndStartListenerBus(SparkContext.scala:2398)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:555)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
    at Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.atlas.AtlasException: Failed to load application properties
    at org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties.get(ApplicationProperties.java:134)
    at org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties.get(ApplicationProperties.java:86)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.AtlasClientConf.configuration$lzycompute(AtlasClientConf.scala:25)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.AtlasClientConf.configuration(AtlasClientConf.scala:25)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.AtlasClientConf.get(AtlasClientConf.scala:50)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.AtlasClient$.atlasClient(AtlasClient.scala:120)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.SparkAtlasEventTracker.<init>(SparkAtlasEventTracker.scala:33)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.SparkAtlasEventTracker.<init>(SparkAtlasEventTracker.scala:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$loadExtensions$1.apply(Utils.scala:2691)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$loadExtensions$1.apply(Utils.scala:2680)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.loadExtensions(Utils.scala:2680)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$setupAndStartListenerBus$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:2387)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$setupAndStartListenerBus$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:2386)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.setupAndStartListenerBus(SparkContext.scala:2386)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.shade.org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: Cannot locate configuration source null
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.shade.org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:259)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.shade.org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:238)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.shade.org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:197)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.shade.org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration.<init>(PropertiesConfiguration.java:284)
    at org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties.<init>(ApplicationProperties.java:69)
    at org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties.get(ApplicationProperties.java:125)
    ... 32 more
19/08/09 16:40:17 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have forgotten one more step from the setup documentation. The error you have stems from

```
Caused by: com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.shade.org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: Cannot locate configuration source null
```

And to quote their README file in the github repo you've posted:

Also make sure atlas configuration file `atlas-application.properties` is in the Driver's classpath. For example, putting this file into `<SPARK_HOME>/conf`.

Comment: I work in Intelijj idea and I start my job there (no console). I created environment SPARK_HOME with folder conf inside and put there atlas-application.properties but anyway something is wrong

Comment: OMG! atlas-application.properties path should be in Properties. I mean in your job it should look like this System.setProperty("atlas.conf", "<path to your properties>").

Answer (score 2):

System.setProperty("atlas.conf", "") is the correct solution as noted by OP.
SAC uses ApplicationProperties.java.

Specifically it uses ApplicationProperties.get.
Source code is here:
https://github.com/apache/atlas/blob/master/intg/src/main/java/org/apache/atlas/ApplicationProperties.java#L118

You can see the variable ATLAS_CONFIGURATION_DIRECTORY_PROPERTY is set to "atlas.conf":
https://github.com/apache/atlas/blob/master/intg/src/main/java/org/apache/atlas/ApplicationProperties.java#L43

Answer (score 1):

please refer to this from the official spark-atlas-connector github page. The atlas-application.properties file should be reachable.

> Also make sure atlas configuration file atlas-application.properties is in the Driver's classpath. For example, putting this file into /conf.
>   If you're using cluster mode, please also ship this conf file to the remote Drive using --files atlas-application.properties.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick. Please note `--files` and `--driver-class-path` options that are necessary to place this configuration file on CLASSPATH and hence available for Atlas Client classes.

Moreover, `spark-shell` uses paths relative to the Spark Atlas Connector so change accordingly.

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell \
  --jars spark-atlas-connector-assembly/target/spark-atlas-connector-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
  --conf spark.extraListeners=com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.SparkAtlasEventTracker \
  --conf spark.sql.queryExecutionListeners=com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.SparkAtlasEventTracker \
  --conf spark.sql.streaming.streamingQueryListeners=com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.SparkAtlasStreamingQueryEventTracker \
  --files spark-atlas-connector/src/test/resources/atlas-application.properties \
  --driver-class-path spark-atlas-connector/src/test/resources
```